# Embedded Linux distribution executes a NTP client not intentionally installed. But which?

Tags: time, embedded-linux, yocto, systemd, ntp

I'm trying to manage the system time of an yocto-base Linux distribution (**zeus** release) by NTP (Network Time protocol).

I know that an available NTP client is `ntpdate`, bu *without installing `ntpdate`, the system time synchronizes itself *with a not known NTP server*.*
The system is connected to Internet by a WiFi network and if I disconnect it from Internet the date synchronization stops.
*This proofs that there is a process running on my distribution which set the system date by a connection to a not known NTP Server.*

Because the distribution comes from the yocto core image `core-image-minimal.bb`, it is one of the packages installed by it which adds a NTP client to the distribution.
**But which is this client?**

I hope I was clear! Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (*and so without that I know it*) in my Linux distribution has been installed the systemd service: `systemd-timesyncd`.

This service starts automatically at boot and, by default, try to connect to one of the following public NTP Server:

```
time1.google.com time2.google.com time3.google.com time4.google.com
```

So it is `systemd-timesyncd` that gets the UTC date and time from one of the previous servers.

About the list of default NTP servers it is useful read the following info from the [timesyncd.conf man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/timesyncd.conf.5.html#CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORIES_AND_PRECEDENCE):

> CONFIGURATION DIRECTORIES AND PRECEDENCE
> The default configuration is defined during **COMPILATION**, so a configuration file is only needed when it is necessary to deviate from those defaults. By default, the configuration file in /etc/systemd/ contains commented out entries showing the defaults as a guide to the administrator. This file can be edited to create local overrides.